# Where are models saved by default?

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I've submitted a training job to the cloud using the [RESTful API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_GB#p/ml/v1beta1/ml.projects.jobs.create) and see in the [console logs](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs) that it completed successfully. In order to deploy the model and use it for predictions I have saved the final model using `tf.train.Saver().save()` (according to the [how-to guide](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/preparing-models#configuring_your_export_files)).

When running locally, I can find the graph files (`export-*` and `export-*.meta`) in the working directory. When running on the cloud however, I don't know where they end up. The API doesn't seem to have a parameter for specifying this, it's not in the bucket with the trainer app, and I can't find any temporary buckets on the cloud storage created by the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set up your Cloud ML environment you set up a bucket for this purpose. Have you looked in there?

https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/getting-set-up

Edit (for future record): As Robert mentioned in comments, you'll want to pass the output location to the job as an argument. Couple of things to be mindful of:

- Use a unique output location per job, so one job doesn't clobber over the outputs of another.
- The recommendation is to specify the parent output path, and use it to contain the exported model in a subpath called 'model', as well as organizing other outputs like checkpoints and summaries within that path. That makes it easier to manage all the outputs.
- While not required, I'll also suggest staging the training code in a packages subpath of the output, which helps correlate the source with the outputs it produces.
- Finally(!), also keep in mind when you use hyperparameter tuning, you'll need to append the trial id to the output path for outputs produced by individual runs.

Comment: I did create a bucket and gave the service account I'm using _editor_ permissions to the bucket itself and set it as _owner_ for all objects as default. After that I put the trainer app in the bucket and ran the job. I don't think this is a permissions issue though, because if it failed to write I should have gotten an error message. From what I can tell, there's nothing linking the bucket to the job apart from the _trainer URI_, or have I missed something?

Comment: Ah, you're right. I guess you need to pass it the 'gs://bucket/model/export' path in trainingInput - args, then pass it to the tf.train.Saver()?

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly now. Previously, my default save path was a relative path, so I guess the output of those runs ended up on the virtual machine running the job and was lost when it was torn down.